# Why does this for each loop not work?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have this code that does not work:

```
Panel[] panelArr = new Panel[5];

for (Panel p:panelArr) {
    p = new Panel();
}
Label lblName = new Label("Name:");
panelArr[0].add(lblName);
```

It comes up with the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at GUIVehicles$NewSportsCarDialog.<init>(GUIVehicles.java:65)
```

However if I replace the for-each loop with this for loop it works.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    panelArr[i] = new Panel();
}
```

As far as I can tell looking through the documentation for the for each loop both for loops should be equivalent. Clearly this is not the case and I was wondering why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your for-each is analogous to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Panel p = panelArr[i];
    p = new Panel();
}
```

Hence the assignment to `p` clearly has no effect on the array itself -- you're just redirecting **`p`** to point somewhere else, which has no bearing on the array. So at the end of the for-each loop, all the array elements are still `null`. Your second snippet is the appropriate way to fill the array.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was certain it was me not understanding it at the most basic level and that was proven to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because `p` is a local variable, it is not `panelArr[i]` directly.

In your first loop you basically assign
the new Panel to `p`, not to `panelArr[i]`.

Think of `p` and `panelArr[i]` as two variables pointing
to objects of type `Panel`. The fact that you initialize
`p` does not mean you also initialized `panelArr[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

In first loop you don't put objects to array. You just iterate over array which has 5 nulls, create local variable `Panel p` (which points to `null`) and assign a `new Panel` object. 
After this loop array still contains 5 nulls.

If you don't have to stick with array, use list instead:

```
List<Panel> panelList = new ArrayList<>(5); //Java7 diamond operator
panelList.add(new Panel());
panelList.add(new Panel());
panelList.add(new Panel());
panelList.add(new Panel());
panelList.add(new Panel());
```

Of course this is not the most elegant way but you will not get NPE.